# How to measure the amount of users connected to a citrix farm

Tags: c#, monitoring, remote-access, citrix

I have an application hosted in a citrix servers farm.
We are writing a monitoring system that needs to measure the total number of connected users to the entire farm.
How can i remotely measure this using .net or bash\powershell script?

thank you in advance.

Comment: This is probably too broad question. Could you be more specific? What have you tried?

Comment: Probably best to try Citrix's own support forum. (I assume it has one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the answer in here http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/332000-count-users-connected-in-farm/

it uses citrix powershell to query all the connections and counts the distinct users connected.